# How to use POST , GET for making search-box in Nodejs

Tags: html, mysql, sql, node.js, parameters

I want to post and get the getparameter keyword from form value and use this query

```
SELECT * from cider.cid_contents 
where con_content like \'%'+ keyword +'%\' 
order by con_no desc;
```

But I don't know how to get the keyword value from post or form method.
There are codes

search.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mysql = require("./model/mysql");

/* GET home page. */
router.post('/search/process', function(req, res, next) {

    var keyword = req.body.keyword;

    console.log(keyword);

    res.redirect('/search');


  });

router.get('/search/:keyword', function(req, res, next) {
    var keyword;
    keyword = req.params.keyword;
    console.log("+++++");
    console.log(keyword+"1234");
    mysql.select('SELECT * from cider.cid_contents where con_content like \'%'+ keyword +'%\' order by con_no desc;',


    function (err, data){
        if (err) throw err;

    res.render('front/search/search', { contents : data});
  });
});


module.exports = router;
```

that's a form tag(top.ejs)

```
<form action="/search/process" method="post">
                <input type="text" class="form-control web-search-box" placeholder="search" name="keyword" value=''></div>
                <div id="search" class="search col-sm-1"><img src="../../page_imgs/fixed_img/icon_search.png"></div>
                <input type="submit" value="send">
                </form>
```

/search (search.ejs)

```
<table class="bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
              <th data-field="no">num</th>
              <th data-field="title">title</th>
              <th data-field="date">date</th>
              <th data-field="viewCount">count</th>
              <th data-field=""></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        <% for(var i = 0; i<contents.length; i++) { %>
            <tr>

                <td><%= contents[i].con_no %></td>
                <td><a href="/adm/contents/detail/<%= contents[i].con_no %>"><%= contents[i].con_title %></a></td>
                <td><%= contents[i].con_regDate %></td>
                <td><%= contents[i].con_viewCount %></td>
                <td><a href="/adm/contents/delete/<%= contents[i].con_no %>">delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        <% } %> 
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use body-parser.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

router.post('/search/process', function(req, res, next) {

  console.log(req.body);

});
```

See https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-expressjs-to-get-url-and-post-parameters#post-parameters for an example.